# What does numerical zero mean at the end of the module main in F#

Tags: visual-studio, f#, xamarin.ios

I generated a F# Xamarin.iOS app from a blank app template.
What does zero at the end mean? Does it mean zero return?

```
namespace FSharpForms.iOS

open UIKit

module Main = 
    [<EntryPoint>]
    let main args = 
        UIApplication.Main(args, null, "AppDelegate") 
        0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Main` method in a .NET application needs to return a numerical code which represents the "exit code" of the process. The value `0` at the end of the `main` function is the return value of the function (it's a bit like writing `return 0` in C-like languages) and `0` indicates that the process completed successfully.

You can find a bit more about [exit codes on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status). Generally, this might be useful when writing a command line tool that is supposed to be called from a script - the exit code is an easy way to indicate to the script calling it whether the tool succeeded or why it failed. However, I'm not sure if the exit codes have particular meaning on iOS that would be useful in your case.